# Angular not working some styles in component?

Tags: angular

I have a `<app-component></<app-component>` which lookes like

```
<div class="vacancy__accordion">
 .....
</div>
```

And I have put the component in one parent div which is flex parent

```
<div class="parent__div">
  <app-component></app-component>
  <div class="another__child"></div>
</div>
```

here is css properties:

```
.parent__div {
  display: flex;
}
.vacancy__accordion {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

And in this moment css is not correctly working on `.vacancy__accordion` due the fact that in `.parent__div` `.vacancy__accordion` is not a direct child of parent component.
If I would place inside `<app-component>` `:host {flex-grow: 1}` it workes but I dont think that it is the best desicioun.
What is the solution in this case ?  Should I make my `<app-component>` to extend the class and tag name or something else ?

Comment: It is. Angular uses css encapsulation. Read more about it on: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

Comment: I think your component should be independent of the parent layout. I think a better design would be wrap around your component in a div and apply the flex-grow css to that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular uses CSS encapsulation. For every Angular component you write, you may define not only an HTML template, but also the CSS styles that go with that template, specifying any selectors, rules, and media queries that you need. One way to do this is to set the styles property in the component metadata.

> The styles specified in @Component metadata apply only within the template of that component.

They are not inherited by any components nested within the template nor by any content projected into the component. Read everything about it on: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles